# phpexcel I/O issues

Tags: php, html, excel

I'm currently using xmapp and attempting to follow this tutorial
http://www.ahowto.net/php/read-and-write-excel-file-using-php-example/

and get this error 
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'if' (T_IF) in /path/location/app

```
    if (!isset($_POST['btnSubmit'])) exit;

    //include PHPExcel library
    require_once('/Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php');

    //load Excel template file
    $objTpl = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load("template.xls");
    $objTpl->setActiveSheetIndex(0);  //set first sheet as active

    $objTpl->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C2', date('Y-m-d'));  //set C1 to current date
    $objTpl->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('C2')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::HORIZONTAL_RIGHT); //C1 is right-justified

    $objTpl->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C3', stripslashes($_POST['txtName']));
    $objTpl->getActiveSheet()->setCellValue('C4', stripslashes($_POST['txtMessage']));

    $objTpl->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('C4')->getAlignment()->setWrapText(true);  //set wrapped for some long text message

    $objTpl->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('C')->setWidth(40);  //set column C width
    $objTpl->getActiveSheet()->getRowDimension('4')->setRowHeight(120);  //set row 4 height
    $objTpl->getActiveSheet()->getStyle('A4:C4')->getAlignment()->setVertical(PHPExcel_Style_Alignment::VERTICAL_TOP); //A4 until C4 is vertically top-aligned

    //prepare download
    $filename=mt_rand(1,100000).'.xls'; //just some random filename
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$filename.'"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

    $objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objTpl, 'Excel5');  //downloadable file is in Excel 2003 format (.xls)
    $objWriter->save('php://output');  //send it to user, of course you can save it to disk also!

    exit; //done.. exiting!

    ?>
```

Comment: A line number might debug this? Otherwise the only thing I can think of is that you've got something above this code segment which isn't closing, or you never have an opening `<?php` tag?

Comment: If we saw the whole file....